# How to enforce type checking of Generic being used twice to be same while still allowing it to be the same?

Tags: typescript, redux

Assume that I have somehow modified Redux that instead of taking a `type:string`, it now takes a `reducer:function` which gets called in the reducer to get the new state.

Now what I want typescript to check is that whatever payload that I am passing is compatible with the second parameter of the reducer.
Please look at the code the following playground and the comments.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20service%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Action%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20State%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Dispatch%20%3D%20(action%3A%20Action%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GetState%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20State%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20setService(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20string)%3AState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20state%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20service%3A%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20incrementCount(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20number)%3A%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20state%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count%3A%20state.count%20%2B%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initAction(dispatch%3ADispatch%2C%20getState%3A%20GetState)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20'todo1'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20incrementCount%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20incrementCount%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20'todo2'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20does%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20action%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(action)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
interface Action<T> {
  reducer: (state: object, payload: T) => object,
  payload: T
}

type Dispatch = (action: Action<any>) => void
```

What allows the two payloads to have different values.
What I intend to create is a type-checked code which checks if the payload is of the correct format that the reducer expects.

What the above translates into is this:

```
type Dispatch2 = (action: {
    reducer: (state: State, payload: any) => State,
    payload: any
}) => void
```

Instead of the two payloads to be any, I want them to be of the same type irrespective of whatever they may actually be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic function signature, and then the compiler will do the apropriate type checks:

```
type Dispatch = <T>(action: Action<T>) => void
```

[Link to updated code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20service%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Action%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20State%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Dispatch%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(action%3A%20Action%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GetState%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20State%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20setService(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20string)%3AState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20state%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20service%3A%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20incrementCount(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20number)%3A%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20state%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count%3A%20state.count%20%2B%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initAction(dispatch%3ADispatch%2C%20getState%3A%20GetState)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20'todo1'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20incrementCount%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20incrementCount%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20'todo2'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20does%20throw%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20action%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reducer%3A%20setService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p)